# JDBC Connection to Snowflake with Private key - without passphrase

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, private-key

I'm working on a Java client based code that is tryint to connect to snowflake JDBC with a private key
I have searched online and found this links:

https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042931854-Snowflake-Using-Key-Pair-Authentication-Connector

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html
and other links, all required to use passphrase

and my code

```
        Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty(USER, jdbcDetails.username);
    String privateKey = jdbcDetails.getPrivateKey().replace("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privateKey = privateKey.replace("\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    String passphrase = "abcdefg";
    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pkInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKey));
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory pbeKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(pkInfo.getAlgName());
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = pkInfo.getKeySpec(pbeKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey encryptedPrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec);
    p.put("privateKey", encryptedPrivateKey);
    return p;
```

It seems this code is valid for connection but after talking with our DBA
he told me that he is able to connect without spesify the passphrase

with this command:

```
snowsql -h a-b-c-d.snowflakecomputing.com -a abcd.AWS_US_EAST-1 -u username  -d  INTEGRATION_ENGINE    --private-key-path ~postgres/ADHOC/12345/rsa_key.p8 -q "select 1"
```

how can i connect using jdbc with a private key - and without passspharse ?

Comment: Are you referring to using a key with passphrase and using a key without? Both are possible and they are documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html#step-1-generate-the-private-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to create 2 types of users with encrypted private key and decrypted private key, this snippet build the private key object and needs to be added to properties

there are 2 instances of - pemObject one for encrypted which requires passPharase and one who dont

//    **pemObject instanceof PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo (encrypted private key)**
// **pemObject instanceof PrivateKeyInfo decypted private key**

```
public class PrivateKeyReader {


    public static PrivateKey get(File file, String passPhrase)
    {
        try {
            PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = null;
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            // Read an object from the private key file.
            final PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(file));
            final Object pemObject = pemParser.readObject();
            if (pemObject instanceof PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) {
                // Handle the case where the private key is encrypted.
                final PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemObject;
                final InputDecryptorProvider pkcs8Prov = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build(passPhrase.toCharArray());
                privateKeyInfo = encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(pkcs8Prov);
            } else if (pemObject instanceof PrivateKeyInfo) {
                // Handle the case where the private key is unencrypted.
                privateKeyInfo = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemObject;
            }
            pemParser.close();
            final JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            return converter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

in order to load it to the connection i used:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = PrivateKeyReader.get(tempPublicKeyFile, jdbcDetails.getDecryptedPassPhrase());
    p.put("privateKey", privateKey);
```